# Creating a GRASS location from a bash script

Tags: grass-gis

I would like to have a GRASS script that creates a new location of its own, instead of using an existing location. This facilitates the usage of the script by other users.

Going through the guide on [Working with GRASS without starting it explicitly](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly) and the notes on [creating locations form the command line](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Location_Wizard#GRASS_GIS_7:_Creating_locations_from_command_line), I arrived at the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
# path to GRASS binaries and libraries:
export GISBASE=/usr/lib/grass74
export PATH=$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib

# GRASS session variables
GRASSDB="/tmp/grassdata"
GRASSLOC="tmp_location"

mkdir -p "$GRASSDB/$GRASSLOC/PERMANENT"

# Create a new GRASS location
#grass74 -c $PATH_IN"ORCDRC_M_sl1_250m_clip.tif" "$GRASSDB$GRASSLOC"

grass74 -c /path/to/some/file.tif "$GRASSDB$GRASSLOC"

echo "Creation done"

# path to GRASS settings file
export GISRC=/tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK/gisrc
# remove any leftover files/folder
rm -fr /tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK
mkdir /tmp/grass7-${USER}-$GIS_LOCK
# set GISDBASE, LOCATION_NAME, and/or MAPSET
echo "GISDBASE: $GRASSDB" >>$GISRC
echo "LOCATION_NAME: $GRASSLOC" >>$GISRC
echo "MAPSET: PERMANENT" >>$GISRC
# start in text mode
echo "GRASS_GUI: text" >>$GISRC

# Test it
g.version
```

This kind of works, however, the `grass74 -c` command not only creates a new location, it also starts a new GRASS session and launches the GUI.

Is there another way of creating a location without launching the GUI (and creating a session)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `grass -c -e -text ...`

from the Help:

```
 -e           exit after creation of location or mapset. Only with -c flag
 -text        use text based interface (skip welcome screen)
```

Comment: --text should be typed with "--"