# Creating a GRASS mapset from a bash script

Tags: grass-gis

This is a follow up to a previous question on the [creation of GRASS locations from a bash script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286921/creating-a-grass-location-from-a-bash-script).

Having successfully created a location, I would now like to create a new mapset within this location. The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# GRASS session variables
GRASSDB="/tmp/grassdata"
GRASSLOC="4326" # This is the EPSG code of the CRS used
GRASSMAP="comparison"

# path to GRASS binaries and libraries:
export GISBASE=/usr/lib/grass74
export PATH=$PATH:$GISBASE/bin:$GISBASE/scripts
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$GISBASE/lib


# Create GRASS database folder
mkdir -p "$GRASSDB"

# Create a new GRASS location
echo "==== Creating new GRASS location ===="
grass74 -c -e "epsg:$GRASSLOC" "$GRASSDB/$GRASSLOC"

echo "==== Creating new mapset ===="
grass74 -c -e "$GRASSDB/$GRASSLOC/$comparison"
```

It produces the following output:

```
$ sh comparison.sh 
==== Creating new GRASS location ====
Cleaning up temporary files...
Creating new GRASS GIS location/mapset...
Cleaning up temporary files...
==== Creating new mapset ====
Cleaning up temporary files...
Creating new GRASS GIS location/mapset...
ERROR: Failed to create new location. The location <4326> already exists.
Exiting...
```

Unlike what is [described in the wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Location_Wizard#GRASS_GIS_7:_Creating_locations_from_command_line), the `-c` argument always attempts to create a new location, and not just a mapset. How can I create just a mapset within an existing location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your the `$comparison` doesn't have a value so it evaluates to nothing.

Thus your 
`grass74 -c -e "$GRASSDB/$GRASSLOC/$comparison"`

evaluates to

`grass74 -c -e "$GRASSDB/$GRASSLOC/"`

which already was made in the previous step.

To tell Bash to raise an error if expands an empty variable write in your top of your script

`set -u`

Comment: Blimey! That was a stupid mistake.