# Creating new GRASS locations while looping in Python script

Tags: python, grass-gis

I am making a Python script for processing my data.

```py
import grass.script as grass
import numpy as np

def main():
     f = open("D:\\Glaciers_selected.csv", 'r')
     fl = f.readlines()
     for x in range(1, len(fl)):
           nf = fl[x].split(';')[1]

           #### Problem in next executable line
           ## I need to create a new location, using the projection from the nf file. 
           grass.read_command('grass76' flags='c' nf ./UTM60S/     ## Here I am stuck

           ## The rest of the script works fine
           grass.read_command('r.import', input= 'D:\\GIS\Farinotti_glaciers\\' + nf + '.tif ', output='RGI60_11', overwrite=True)
           grass.read_command('g.region', raster='RGI60_11', flags='a', overwrite=True) 
           ...
           ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My script runs fine if I start GRASS, add a new location with the location wizard and then run each line, one by one from the Python tab in the layer manager. However, I do not know how to add a location once I am inside a loop of a Python script.

When I run grass76 -c  from the console, the location Wizard appears ...

I read [Creating a GRASS location from a bash script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/286921/creating-a-grass-location-from-a-bash-script) and there seems to be a way of doing this, but I was not able to follow the explanation (which is for BASH, by the way, not for Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the `g.proj` command with the `-c` flag. However without knowing what's in your Glaciers_selected.csv file, I can't know how to specify the coordinate reference system. The `-c` flag for `g.proj` (just like `grass -c ...`) requires either a georeferenced data file, an EPSG code, or the full proj.4 CRS specification.

Here's an example. I start in a location defined as Pseudo Mercator, EPSG 3857, and create a new location based on a georeferenced shapefile in EPSG 4326. I switch to that location, then import the layer projected in that CRS (EPSG 4326):

```
micha@RMS World $ ipython
Python 2.7.15+ (default, Nov 27 2018, 23:36:35) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

import grass.script as gscript

# Show current location CRS
gscript.run_command('g.proj', flags="p")
-PROJ_INFO-------------------------------------------------
name       : WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
a          : 6378137
es         : 0
proj       : merc
lat_ts     : 0.0
lon_0      : 0.0
x_0        : 0.0
y_0        : 0
k          : 1.0
wktext     : defined
no_defs    : defined
-PROJ_EPSG-------------------------------------------------
epsg       : 3857
-PROJ_UNITS------------------------------------------------
unit       : Meter
units      : Meters
meters     : 1

# Now create a new location, using a georeferenced file
gscript.run_command('g.proj', flags="c", georef="Mediterranean.shp", location="longlat")
Location <longlat> created
You can switch to the new location by
`g.mapset mapset=PERMANENT location=longlat`

# Change to that new location, and display new CRS parameters
gscript.run_command('g.mapset', location="longlat", mapset="PERMANENT")
Mapset switched. Your shell continues to use the history for the old mapset
You can switch the history by commands:
history -w; history -r
/home/micha/work/tmp/longlat/PERMANENT/.bash_history;
HISTFILE=/home/micha/work/tmp/longlat/PERMANENT/.bash_history

gscript.run_command('g.proj', flags="p")
-PROJ_INFO-------------------------------------------------
name       : WGS 84
datum      : wgs84
ellps      : wgs84
proj       : ll
no_defs    : defined
-PROJ_UNITS------------------------------------------------
unit       : degree
units      : degrees
meters     : 1.0

gscript.run_command('v.import', input_="Mediterranean.shp", output="med")
Check if OGR layer <Mediterranean> contains polygons...
 100%
Creating attribute table for layer <Mediterranean>...
Default driver / database set to:
driver: sqlite
database: $GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db
Importing 2 features (OGR layer <Mediterranean>)...
 100%
# ....additional output lines of cleaning etc...
Input <Mediterranean.shp> successfully imported without reprojection
```

Note that the new location has the CRS of the input file, and so the `v.import` command does NOT need the `-o` parameter.

You can, of course, wrap the above in a loop, and create a new location for each input file if needed. But you must have the correct CRS available either as a georeferenced file, EPSG code, or the full specification.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you create a new location from inside a python script:

```
grass.core.create_location(dbase='C:\\grassdata\\Glaciers\\PERMANENT\\sqlite', location='Lnew', filename='D:\\Farinotti_glaciers\\RGI60-11.00015.tif', overwrite=True)
```

dbase:    is the path to GRASS database
location: location name to create
file:     if given create new location based on georeferenced file

Additional arguments can be found in: [Python documentation - script package - submodules](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/libpython/script.html#script.core.create_location)